# Simple Calendar Wordpress Plugin - how can I show only the event title?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin called Simple Calendar

The problem is that it shows me way more stuff than I need, because I only need the "event title" of the current day (from google calendar)
I've succeded to get away the table
I picked the list view instead of grid
But what I need is to have only the Event Title to use inside a content
I cant find a way to do so.
Maybe a shortcode? a php hook?
This is the code that I have

```
<div class="simcal-calendar simcal-default-calendar simcal-default-calendar-list simcal-default-calendar-light simcal-default-calendar-light simcal-default-calendar-light" data-calendar-id="355" data-timezone="Europe/Rome" data-offset="3600" data-week-start="1" data-calendar-start="1606950000" data-calendar-end="1638485941" data-events-first="1606086059" data-events-last="1638485941"><p class="simcal-align-right"><small><a class="post-edit-link" href="https://www.websitename.it/wp-admin/post.php?post=355&amp;action=edit">Edit Calendar</a></small></p><div class="simcal-calendar-list simcal-calendar-list-compact"><div class="simcal-events-list-container" data-prev="1606863600" data-next="1607036400" data-heading-small="2020, 03 Dic" data-heading-large="03/12/2020"><div class="simcal-weekday-4 simcal-past simcal-day simcal-day-has-events simcal-day-has-1-events simcal-events-calendar-355" data-events-count="1">
    <ul class="simcal-events">
    <li class="simcal-event simcal-event-recurring simcal-events-calendar-355" style="" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" data-start="1606950059">
        <div class="simcal-event-details"><p><strong><span class="simcal-event-title" itemprop="name">plastic</span></strong></p>
<p><span class="simcal-event-start simcal-event-start-date" data-event-start="1606950059" data-event-format="d/m/Y" itemprop="startDate" content="2020-12-03T00:00:59+01:00">03/12/2020</span><br>
 <span class="simcal-event-address simcal-event-start-location" itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta itemprop="name" content="plastic"><meta itemprop="address" content="plastic"></span></p>
<div></div>
<p> <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=M3ZsYzlsMmEwZWpoamdqNGttZDE0aGYzMGZfMjAyMDEyMDMgczA2aGFsM3Y0OGVzbDg2cmVxbjJwOWpsOG9AZw&amp;ctz=Europe/Rome" target="_blank">See more details</a></p></div>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div><div class="simcal-ajax-loader simcal-spinner-top" style="display: none;"><i class="simcal-icon-spinner simcal-icon-spin"></i></div></div></div>
```

I only need to reach the event title that in this case is "plastic"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

Do not edit the plugin, as any amendments you make will be overwritten if you update it in the future. You could add some custom css to hide the other details.

`.simcal-events span:not(.simcal-event-title) { display:none; }`

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'll try this as soon as I get home

But, can you please tell me what that CSS is about?
I'm trying to learn

Thank you